# Prove possible key for Mono alphabetic Cipher

Tags: encryption

I am currently learning the Mono alphabetic Cipher Encryption. For an example, for 26 letters substitution ciphers.

Suppose the letter identified with each other.
So the total possible key is 26!

And the can I know how to prove that: 26!>= 4*10^26 ????

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
log_10(26!) = log_10(26) + log_10(25) + ... + log_10(2) + log_10(1)
            = 26.60562
```

Thus,

```
 26! = 10 ^ (26.60562) = (10 ^ 0.60562) * 10^26
```

Since

```
 log_10(4) = 0.6020
```

We could get `26! > 4 * 10^26`.